# Unable to access .NET Core application from Public IP

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon EC2 Windows running an ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC web application (Hello World). I installed [.NET 7.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) before deploying, building and running the HelloWorld app.

Code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Run(async context =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path.Value == "/")
    {
       await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World 2");
    }
 });

app.Run();
```

`launchSettings.json`:

```
"http": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5223",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
"https": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "dotnetRunMessages": true,
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7174;http://localhost:5223",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
},
```

**Security Group**

I have HTTPS 443, HTTP 80 open. Besides since my .NET Core app is running on HTTPS 7174 and HTTP 5223, I have opened it as well. RDP 3389 is open as well. For Outbound rules, all open.

Screenshot:

[image]

Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security is also enabled Inbound Rules for HTTPS 443, HTTP 40, WebApp HTTP 5223 and WebApp HTTPS 7174. Screenshot attached, can provide more on request for each entry.

[image]

**Question/Problem**

I'm unable to access the Hello World app using *Public IPv4* address or *Public IPv4 DNS* provided by the EC2 instance.

---

**Edit**

I'm using `dotnet run` to start the service

[image]

Comment: Is the ec2 instance running behind a load balancer? Is it located inside a private subnet? What error are you getting when you send request to your website?

Comment: Can you access it from the instance itself by going to `localhost` in your browser?

Comment: Did you use `dotnet run` to launch the web application on EC2 or you are using IIS?

Comment: @AnkushJain I'm using `dotnet run`, see the edit and the screenshot please

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes it's accessible, see the screenshot towards the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this link [External Network Access to Kestrel and IIS Express in ASP.NET Core](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core)

> In order to expose Kestrel externally you either have to bind to a specific machine name, IP Address or 0.0.0.0 which stands for all IP Addresses (thanks to @DamianEdwards and @BradyMHolt for their help).

If you run the application with the below command, it should work.

```
dotnet run --urls http://0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: Make sure you are using http while accessing the website, not https. It is working with http, I verified from your IP.